# i want to write a code in golang. program reads 100 url from file and print its status code

Tags: go

how can i pass url via for loop in get request i have read a file and want to pass it on get request
but i have a problem in for loop can anybody help me

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("url.txt")

    resp, err := http.Get(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Print the HTTP Status Code and Status Name
    fmt.Println("HTTP Response Status:", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))

    if resp.StatusCode >= 200 && resp.StatusCode <= 299 {
        fmt.Println("HTTP Status is in the 2xx range")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Argh! Broken")
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to call `http.Get` in loop for multiple urls in the file `url.txt`?

Comment: yes urls stored in url.txt

Comment: can you add the example for the `url.txt` and the issue you are facing updating the code with `for` loop?

Comment: url.txt contain url like https://shop.example.com https://fordexampl.com and i want to read it from file and parse info http.get function i unable to make loop

Answer (score 1):

You should use `os` package instead of `io/ioutil` package as described in the ioutil package:

> As of Go 1.16, the same functionality is now provided by package io or
> package os, and those implementations should be preferred in new code.
> See the specific function documentation for details.

This will also avoid unnecessary conversion from `byte` returned by `ioutil.ReadFile()` to  `string` object required by `http.Get()`.

Further, you can use the `NewScanner()` method from the `bufio` package to read line by line.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("url.txt") // open the file
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        resp, err := http.Get(scanner.Text()) // call http.Get per URL object
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // Print the HTTP Status Code and Status Name
        fmt.Println("HTTP Response Status:", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))

        if resp.StatusCode >= 200 && resp.StatusCode <= 299 {
            fmt.Println("HTTP Status is in the 2xx range")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Argh! Broken")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The input will by default be splitted on newline character.

Comment: remove  # open the file  # call http.Get per URL object tags  from above code and it will work fine thanks for help

Comment: ahh, habit of working with python where the comments are added with `#` as opposed to `//` in golang.